# Sending mail notification for manual sharing

Tags: email, sharing, notification

I have custom object which is private where users share records with other users manually. I want to send email notification to the shared user whenever a record is shared to him. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It always helps if you provide information about the research you have already done. What have you tried, what exactly can't you figure out...

Answer (score 2):

You can query back the share records .share records will have userId with whom its shared and also the record Id so all you will need to do is use messaging.email to send to the respective users

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm

Here is the document link you can use to get started .

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm

Above on how to use outbound email functionality.